# Angular 2 new files doesn't detect changes

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an existing project of Angular 2. I added few modules on that project and on the files I added changes are not being detected.

I tried googling how these detect changes work in angular 2 but didn't get the right answer. Can anyone help me direct in which settings/files should I be looking into if I have to enable detect change and compile my new modules in Angular 2.

Comment: need to know more about your setup?

Comment: @Matthias What setup are we talking about ? And could you not down vote for asking questions that I don't know.

Comment: Any setup, what are you using which should detect the changes? (grunt, gulp, angular cli, whatever I don't know) Angular itself is just javascript and does not come built with compiling tools/frameworks. I did not downvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the angular cli you can run the command ng serve to detect changes and run your application at localhost:4200. Or you can run the command ng build --watch to observe changes. You will need to manually refresh the browser each time this recompiles.

Comment: The problem is its detecting changes for existing files outside the submodule in app folder but not inside modules.